# "Invalid neighbor parameter" error. Trying to create static arp using netsh

Tags: windows-7, networking, arp, netsh

I am trying to make a static arp entry for my gateway 192.168.2.1. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and at first I tried:

```
arp -s 192.168.2.1 00-11-22-33-44-55
```

But I was getting a permission denied error so I started to look around and found out that on Windows 7 64 bit I need to use netsh.
I found some commands on some other posts to try but the add neighrbors command responds with

`Invalid neighbor parameter (00:11:22:33:44:55).`

every time that I try.

I first used this command which seems to work:

```
netsh interface ipv4 delete neighbors
```

And then this is the command that gets an error

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors "Local Area Connection" "192.168.2.1" "00:11:22:33:44:55"
```

I also tried without the quotes and got the same response with this.

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors "Local Area Connection" 192.168.2.1 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

It doesn't make sense to me because if I run:

```
netsh interface ipv4 delete neighbors "Local Area Connection" "192.168.2.1" "00:11:22:33:44:55"
```

It works just fine and gives me the Ok response so I am not sure what is going on. Does anyone have any suggestions? I am also running cmd as admin and I do know my correct gateway mac address.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. Turns out that I was using the wrong mac.